# Two timelines with tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create two timelines with tikzpicture. The top one looks as I want, but I'm having troubles with the bottom one. Instead of having little vertical tick marks I'm generating big diagonals.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% Resize table to fit within
\begin{tikzpicture}[snake=zigzag, line before snake = 5mm, line after snake = 5mm]
%draw horizontal line
\draw (0,0) -- (19/2,0);
\draw[snake] (19/2,0) -- (25/2,0);
\draw (25/2,0) -- (30/2,0);
\draw[snake] (30/2,0) -- (35/2,0);
\draw (35/2,0) -- (40/2,0);
%draw vertical lines
\foreach \x in {0, 5, 10, 19, 30, 40}{
   \draw (\x/2,3pt) -- (\x/2,-3pt);
}
%draw nodes
\draw (-2,0) node { PHYS1060 };

\draw (0,0) node[below=3pt] { Pre-test published } node[above=3pt] { Jan 4, 2014  };
\draw (5/2,0) node[below=3pt] { Nudge } node[above=3pt] { Jan 9, 2014  };
\draw (10/2,0) node[below=3pt] { First class } node[above=3pt] { Jan 13, 2014  };
\draw (19/2,0) node[below=3pt] { Pre-test due } node[above=3pt] { Jan 22, 2014  };
\draw (30/2,0) node[below=3pt] { Midterm } node[above=3pt] { Feb 17, 2014  };
\draw (40/2,0) node[below=3pt] { Final Exam} node[above=3pt] { May 5, 2014  };


%draw horizontal line
\draw (-2,-2) node { PHYS1050 };
\draw (0,-2) -- (19/2,-2);
\draw[snake] (19/2,-2) -- (25/2,-2);
\draw (25/2,-2) -- (30/2,-2);
\draw[snake] (30/2,-2) -- (35/2,-2);
\draw (35/2,-2) -- (40/2,-2);
draw vertical lines
\foreach \x in {0, 5, 10, 19, 30, 40}{
   \draw (\x/2,-2,3pt) -- (\x/2,-2,-3pt);
}


%draw nodes
\draw (0,-2) node[below=3pt] { Pre-test published } node[above=3pt] { Aug 10, 2014  };
\draw (5/2,-2) node[below=3pt] { First class } node[above=3pt] { Aug 27, 2014  };
\draw (10/2,-2) node[below=3pt] { Nudge } node[above=3pt] { Sept 4, 2014  };
\draw (19/2,-2) node[below=3pt] { Pre-test due } node[above=3pt] { Sept 7, 2014  };
\draw (30/2,-2) node[below=3pt] { Midterm } node[above=3pt] { ?, 2014  };
\draw (40/2,-2) node[below=3pt] { Final Exam} node[above=3pt] { ?, 2014  };

\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please complete your code in order to have a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: `(\x/2,-2,3pt)` is a 3-dimensional coordinate. Is that supposed to be that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would explicitly define the coordinates of your vertical lines.

So your first vertical lines would become:

```
\foreach \x in {0, 5, 10, 19, 30, 40}{
   \draw (\x/2,-0.2) -- (\x/2,0.2);
}
```

and the second set would be

```
\foreach \x in {0, 5, 10, 19, 30, 40}{
   \draw (\x/2,-2.2) -- (\x/2,-1.8);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's better to provide full examples instead of fragments ;-)

Comment: Thanks. But surely if you're only changing one or two lines of the original MWE, that's a lot of unnecessary text?

Comment: I think it's more about making it easier for the OP and others to use your answer: as it is now, you'd have to copy the MWE, then copy your fragment, and paste it in the appropriate place. If you include the corrected MWE you make everything easier. Besides, the beauty of _minimal_ examples if that they will never be very big. :)

Answer (score 2):

The calculation of the y-coordinate for the vertical lines in the second case is wrong. In the first case it works, because the horizontal line is at height `0`.
In the second case you have to add the offset `-2`, which can be achieved with the `calc`-library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% Resize table to fit within
\begin{tikzpicture}[snake=zigzag, line before snake = 5mm, line after snake = 5mm]
%draw horizontal line
\draw (0,0) -- (19/2,0);
\draw[snake] (19/2,0) -- (25/2,0);
\draw (25/2,0) -- (30/2,0);
\draw[snake] (30/2,0) -- (35/2,0);
\draw (35/2,0) -- (40/2,0);
%draw vertical lines
\foreach \x in {0, 5, 10, 19, 30, 40}{
   \draw (\x/2,3pt) -- (\x/2,-3pt);
}
%draw nodes
\draw (-2,0) node { PHYS1060 };

\draw (0,0) node[below=3pt] { Pre-test published } node[above=3pt] { Jan 4, 2014  };
\draw (5/2,0) node[below=3pt] { Nudge } node[above=3pt] { Jan 9, 2014  };
\draw (10/2,0) node[below=3pt] { First class } node[above=3pt] { Jan 13, 2014  };
\draw (19/2,0) node[below=3pt] { Pre-test due } node[above=3pt] { Jan 22, 2014  };
\draw (30/2,0) node[below=3pt] { Midterm } node[above=3pt] { Feb 17, 2014  };
\draw (40/2,0) node[below=3pt] { Final Exam} node[above=3pt] { May 5, 2014  };


%draw horizontal line
\draw (-2,-2) node { PHYS1050 };
\draw (0,-2) -- (19/2,-2);
\draw[snake] (19/2,-2) -- (25/2,-2);
\draw (25/2,-2) -- (30/2,-2);
\draw[snake] (30/2,-2) -- (35/2,-2);
\draw (35/2,-2) -- (40/2,-2);
draw vertical lines
\foreach \x in {0, 5, 10, 19, 30, 40}{
   \draw ($(0,-2)+(\x/2, 3pt)$) -- ($(0,-2)+(\x/2, -3pt)$);
}


%draw nodes
\draw (0,-2) node[below=3pt] { Pre-test published } node[above=3pt] { Aug 10, 2014  };
\draw (5/2,-2) node[below=3pt] { First class } node[above=3pt] { Aug 27, 2014  };
\draw (10/2,-2) node[below=3pt] { Nudge } node[above=3pt] { Sept 4, 2014  };
\draw (19/2,-2) node[below=3pt] { Pre-test due } node[above=3pt] { Sept 7, 2014  };
\draw (30/2,-2) node[below=3pt] { Midterm } node[above=3pt] { ?, 2014  };
\draw (40/2,-2) node[below=3pt] { Final Exam} node[above=3pt] { ?, 2014  };

\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\draw[shift=(down:2)] (\x/2, 3pt) -- (\x/2, -3pt);` should work as well and does not need the `calc` library. You also don't have to add the offset twice. Actually, it might be best to put the whole second part in a scope with the option `shift=(down:2)` (or `2cm` for this kind of specification).